# Get id of last inserted document in laravel after save() using mongodb

Tags: ajax, mongodb, laravel

Here is a code

```
public function addItem(Request $req)
{
    $data = new UserModel();
    $data->Name = $req->name;
    $data->IP=$req->ip;
    $data->username=$req->username;
    $data->password=$req->password;
    $data->save();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Comment: Are you using any package to use mongodb?

Comment: Yes I'm using jenssegers/mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I asked I'm not getting the id. I'm getting this error because after insertion. if you want to get id it must get like `data->_id` not `data->id` as I get the id `data.id` in ajax so I write code as below:

```
$data = new UserModel();
$data->Name = $req->name;
$data->IP=$req->ip;
$data->username=$req->username;
$data->password=$req->password;
$data->save();
$data->id=$data->_id;
return response()->json($data);
```

and in Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/addItem',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'name': $('#en').val(),
            'ip': $('#eip').val(),
            'username': $('#eun').val(),
            'password': $('#ep').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if ((data.errors)){
                $('.error').removeClass('d-none');
                $('.error').text(data.errors.name);
            }
            else {
                $('.error').addClass('d-none');
                $('#table').append("<tr class='item" + data.id + "'><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.IP + "</td><td>" + data.Name + "</td><td>" + data.username + "</td><td>" + data.password + "</td><td><button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-name='" + data.Name + "' data-ip='" + data.IP + "' data-username='" + data.username + "' data-password='" + data.password + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button> <button class='delete-modal btn btn-danger' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-name='" + data.Name + "' data-ip='" + data.IP + "' data-username='" + data.username + "' data-password='" + data.password + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button></td></tr>");
            }
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `$data` in this case is an object, you can access ID with:

```
$id = $data->id;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply I already test it, giving output undefined............

Comment: `undefined` is JS type. You're getting the error in JS? Please show what does `dd($data->id)` shows exactly if you put it right after `$data->save()`?

Comment: when I access it from js it will give 'undefined'

Comment: On `success:function()` call. I'm appending table, when I access `data.id` it will give undefined....

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel, after saving or creating a new model that uses auto-incrementing IDs, you may retrieve the ID by accessing the object's id attribute:

```
$data->save();
$id = $data->id;
```